# How to parse parameters to __layout.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I parse some parameters to __layout.cshtml?

```
public class BaseInfo {
      public string ShowMenu {get; set;}
      public bool IsLoggedIn {get; set;}
      public string CustomerName {get; set;}
      .....
}
```

In __layout.cshtml, I would like to access these field, what is the best way for me to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a custom WebViewPage class.

Comment: You should use `ViewBag`.

Comment: any example for custom "WebViewPage"? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as model

```
@model NamespaceName.ModelsFolderName.BaseInfo
```

also you can use

```
ViewBag
ViewBag.CustomerName = BaseInfoObject.CustomerName;
```

to store any infornmation in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use child actions. Creating a custom `WebViewPage` class is just insane, and setting a model on your layout is just asking for trouble. If you do that, then *every single view* must then use that model or a subclass of that model, as well. Worst case scenario, you'll have at least one view that needs a different type of model; best case scenario, your entire business domain is defined by something you need in the UI (huge no-no).

Child actions are like partials, in that you can just drop them anywhere in your layout or view, but unlike partials, they get their own separate context that doesn't effect anything else going on in the layout or view.

**FooController.cs**

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    ...

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DisplayBaseInfo()
    {
        var baseInfo = new BaseInfo(); // pull from database or construct the instance however you like here
        return PartialView("_DisplayBaseInfo", baseInfo);
    }
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@Html.Action("DisplayBaseInfo", "Foo")
```

Put that call wherever you need to display the information in this instance. It doesn't matter what controller you put the child action in; just put it somewhere that makes sense to your application. Obviously, you'll need to create the partial view `_DisplayBaseInfo.cshtml` and then render the `BaseInfo` instance however you like there. In that view you *can* set the model as `BaseInfo` and work strongly-typed, without affecting anything else.

This way, there's *zero* dependencies. Everything can use standard MVC classes, without having to modify the page class or remember to have every view model inherit from some base class.